# JavaScript removed Addchooce icon in Google AdSense

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove AddChoose icon (top, right corner) in Google AdSense using JavaScript

```
 window.onload = function () { 
 //    alert($('#google_ads_frame1').contents().find("body").html());

 var iframeInner = $('iframe').find('html').contents();

 var iframeContent = $(iframeInner).contents().find('#google_ads_frame1');
 var aa = $(iframeContent).contents().find('body');
 var divInnerFormText = aa.find("#google_ads_frame1").text();
```

I want to det the content inside google_ads_frame1

Comment: This is forbidden, plus windows having their document on differents domains do not have access to each other

Comment: is there any possibility to hide it

Comment: Putting a white backgrounded div over it